# How update only selected fields (anonymouse type-to-strong type) in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

So in my Entity I have large columns that I dont need in my View. For don't load large columns I use anonymouse type with cast to strong Type

```
       _ctx = new hModelContainer();
       var skAnonym = from s in _ctx.Sketches
                         where s.SketchStatus.Id == 0
                         select new
                         {
                             s.Id,
                             s.Number,
                             s.Author,
                             s.SketchStatus,
                             s.Title,
                             s.Comments
                         };

            var skStrong = skAnonymt.AsEnumerable().Select(s =>
                         new Sketch
                         {
                             Id = s.Id,
                             Number = s.Number,
                             Author = s.Author,
                             SketchStatus = s.SketchStatus,
                             Title = s.Title,
                             Comments = s.Comments
                         });

            _sketchs = skStrong.ToList();
```

then I update my `_sketchs` collection in WPF View and want save it to DB. If I tried to do it directly `_ctx.SaveChanges()`; I have an exeption

> "...can't insert NULL to noNulleable
>   field TextXML"

and `TextXML` is the name of column that I didn't load from DB because it's large and I don't need it in my View.
So how to update existing Entity from my View?

Comment: The use of an anonymous type in your scenario is completely useless. Just create a new Sketch directly. This doesn't solve your problem however.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, his Sketch class is a Entity. You can't create a new Entity class in LINQ query like this. (Try it.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid loading big fields check [table splitting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/12/05/table-splitting-mapping-multiple-entity-types-to-the-same-table.aspx). It will save you a lot of effort because you will mostly work only with entity which will not contain that fields.

If you don't want to use table splitting you must manually say to context which fields should be updated:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.Attach(sketch);
    ObjectStateEntry entry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(sketch);
    entry.SetModifiedProperty("Number");
    ...
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: SetModifiedProperty cannot be called because the object is not in a modified or unchanged state

Comment: If the object is not in any of these states then you are doing something wrong because object is either detached and will not be modified at all or is added (context will insert new object) or deleted.

Comment: So my sketch is in Added state. Why not modified state? I have the code see above + in foreach 'code item.Comments = DateTime.Now.ToString();
_ctx.Attach(item);
ObjectStateEntry entry = _ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(item);
                    entry.SetModifiedProperty("Comments");

Comment: Is this EF4 (not earlier EF)?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka thank you very much for help - I decided to use entity splitting

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I created a test table like this:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Data2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] (Data1,Data2) VALUES ('Row 1 - Data 1', 'Row1 - Data 2')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] (Data1,Data2) VALUES ('Row 2 - Data 1', 'Row2 - Data 2')
GO
```

In VS I imported this table with the wizard into Entity model. Then I wrote the following code:

```
        TestEntities ctx = new TestEntities();
        var data = from d in ctx.MyTables select new { d.Id, d.Data1 };
        var data2 = data.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new MyTable(){Id = x.Id, Data1 =  x.Data1 });
        var data3 = data2.ToList();

        foreach (var item in data3)
        {
            ctx.MyTables.Attach(item);
        }

        data3[0].Data1 = "Hello";            

        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

After executing this code I looked at the database and checked that the value has changed to "Hello".

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Exeption when _ctx.Attach(sketch); object in Added state. So i'm turn to table spitting...

Comment: What I found useful doing, is taking a sample that you know works, and the one that does not (your code) and step by step closing the gap. Somewhere in between you always find the reason and you also learn something in process.